# Android ListView Alternating Selector

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I currently have a ListView which contains a Radiobutton and a TextView on each row. The ListView uses a custom adapter, and I've given the ListView the android:choiceMode="singleChoice" directive, to insure only a single element could be chosen from the list. However, I can't seem to highlight the selected item.

Here is the XML declaration of the ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/employees_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borderlist"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
                android:listSelector="#48ad82"
                android:layout_below="@id/employees_header">
 </ListView>
```

Here is the XML declaration of the ListView's rows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_employee"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="13dp"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_employeename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radio_employee"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since I want to alternate the row's colors, I set a selector on each row by programming, I have this bit of code in the custom adapter's getView:

```
// Alternate row colors.
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list1);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list2);
    }
```

Here is the XML declaration for selector_list1, selector_list2 is identical except for the for the first drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightgreen_listpressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"  android:drawable="@color/lightgreen_listpressed" />
</selector>
```

State_pressed works, but I tried using state_activated, state_selected, state_enabled, state_checked and nothing works out to change the color of the selected list item. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT 1: If I simply throw my selectors out of the window (IE not use them), selection coloring works with only the android:listSelector="#48ad82" directive I have in the ListView declaration. Why doesn't this work with the selectors?

EDIT 2: Tried all the different states again, including state_focused when removing the listSelector directive entirely. Still no results.

EDIT 3: I suppose the issue is that the ListView itself allows the selection, the RelativeLayout view never really gets "selected" persay, thus setting the selector on it is useless. If that's the case, where and how am I supposed to set the selectors to have them do what I want them to do?

EDIT 4: I tried setting colors on the adapter based on this tutorial: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/ No results, I still don't get any selection color unless I call android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" which hides all the elements in the ListView element.

EDIT 5: I'm going to drop this for now and just remove the alternating colors altogether. None of the explanations I have found on StackOverflow or Google talk about this issue. The only way to make this "work" is to call android:drawSelectorOnTop="true", which does change the color of the element currently selected in the ListView, however, it hides everything in that one row.

Comment: Did you try with a transparent selector? `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: I would also try to add `android:clickable="true"` to the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do anything to trigger my selector colors, and overall does nothing since the color is transparent.State_pressed still triggers and changes the color of the ListView item to @color/lightgreen_listpressed as long as the item is pressed.

Comment: No dice. Added the clickable="true" directive to the RelativeLayout. The behavior of the ListView doesn't change.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, adding the clickable directive breaks the listSelector on the ListView

Comment: You could try putting the selector on top, but using alpha to allow the controls to show through, rather than solid colour which will cover them up.

Comment: That's an idea but not an optimal solution sadly.

Comment: You'd probably want to read this http://chris.banes.me/2013/03/22/checkable-views/